# Receiving payment for apps on the App Store

Tags: iphone, app-store

Could someone here tell me the process Apple follows once your app is put on the app store?

1. Does the credit card with which the developers program was bought get credited with the amount made on the app?
2. Does Apple allow you to create/setup a separate account to receive income from the app?

Any direction to this will be really helpful.

Comment: We're starting a proposal for questions like this on Area 51: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/54103/app-stores?referrer=Znmz97Ak7ERjuiuCuAdO9A2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As part of the developer program you need to set up your bank account details - it's all on the iTunes Connect website. Then they'll pay you monthly.

Hence it will be separate from your credit card. Of course if you use your bank's debit card then it is the same account.

Comment: Perfect. Thats what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Apple will ask for a payment account as part of their certification process. I believe the payments are made in a lump, so I don't think you can split that into separate accounts.